# Use Padding to keep child elements in center by css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I make a child elements to flow horizontally ,and want to keep them in center by using CSS,I know their are many ways to keep it in center by using css only, but i want to use padding to keep child element in center of window height,

**Why Padding :** I am working on IE-11 ,and if i keep my element in center by applying :

```
#mycontainer{ min-height:450px;top:20%;bottom:20%;}
```

then scroll only happens when mouse is over or focus is on `#mycontainer`,

so by applying padding :

```
#mycontainer{ height:100%;padding:20% 0 20% 100px;}
```

my scroll works everywhere on a page but this not keeps elements in center.

So, for now i achieve this by using jquery :

```
var padding = ($(window).height() - content_height) / 2;

$('#mycontainer').css({ 'padding': (padding+'px') + ' 0 ' + (padding+'px') + ' 100px' });
```

Is this possible by using CSS only ?

[**Here is my Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/CTVc6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `display:flex` to do this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjGBF/

or `display:table` http://jsfiddle.net/MxE8Y/2/ (includes IE8)

Comment: can you link the fiddle where it does not work ? and tell wich browser you use ? :)

Comment: your fiddle CSS has nothing similar to any of the 2 example /technics given ?? Actually , that's how it works. http://jsfiddle.net/MxE8Y/3/

Comment: for nothing but a single image in background: in body for instance : background:url(image) no-repeat center;